# System image to restore windows 7 on new 2 in 1 laptop.

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop, system-restore, windows-7-restore

Recently, my old lenovo L440, running windows 7 64bit had some damage to the motherboard leading to a replacement computer. I purchased a Lenovo Yoga 730 2 in 1 with the i7 8550U processor which runs windows10 64bit and has a SSD.

I have a recent system image which I'd like to use to on the new computer. For starters, I dislike the windows 10, and asked the clerk if I could just get a model with Windows 7 installed. He said its not offered or compatible with current models / gave some hand wavy explanation why. Something about cores/ threads in the new intel processors and optimization of windows 10 for modern hardware? He also mentioned how the 2 in 1 screens require windows 10? I needed this computer ASAP for work so didn't fuss with trying to find a refurbished computer running Windows 7 and just went and got this replacement. However, I have various directories, packages, libraries etc in python, R, IRAF, and FIJI setup in such a way that it would just be a lot easier to transfer everything over with the system image rather than re-installing everything from scratch again and adjusting things with the code errors due to new paths and files invariably come up.

My question is, is there any real risk to restoring my old system image on the new computer / is there some optimization of windows 10 for modern hardware that windows 7 lacks? I can't see why the new hardware should be incompatible with windows 7 and everything else from my old image?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any real risk to restoring my old system image on the new computer / is there some optimization of windows 10 for modern hardware that windows 7 lacks? I can't see why the new hardware should be incompatible with windows 7 and everything else from my old image?

Yes, there is. The TL;DR is **it won't boot**.

Windows 7 is not compatible with the new hardware of a Lenovo Yoga 730 2 in 1. But even if it was - in a parallel Universe - it wouldn't boot due to other issues you aren't considering, the main reason being the old Windows 7 is a BIOS installation and the new hardware requires UEFI. Your "old image" is in itself incompatible with pretty much anything that is considerably different than the original hardware, even with PCs contemporary with your old PC.